# Save Starting And ShutDown Time Of windows In Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, time, shutdown

I am On Windows 8.1  , And want to create a script that check when the computer is started and When It Is Turned Off.
Like I Turned On My Laptop,The Script Starts And Save The Date,Time as Text File In `D:/` drive And When I shutdown My Laptop,While Shutting Down The Script Will Save The time,Date.
And The Text file will Be Like:

```
26 Jun,2017  : 3:47 AM
-------------TO-----------
26 Jun,2017  : 4:16 AM
```

I really Want That Script,It would Be So Helpful For Me.
But Sometimes I think how Will The Script Save Text While Shutting Down,The Windows will Quickly Close That Script But
Placing It On Folder:

```
C:/Windows
```

Maybe Will Work Because It will run as Admin and save text before shutting down.
Hope You Will Get It.

Comment: You can get information about shutdown events when the machine boots up again apparently. https://superuser.com/a/277292 looks useful. I notice too that according to http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/30364-check-your-pc-shutdown-startup-log-forensic-way.html there are some other possible events. I don't know that there's an especially useful role for Python here. It would appear that PowerShell is the thing to use.

Comment: It Can't Be Done In Python??We Will Create Shortcut Of **File.pyw** And Place It in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` ,When Windows Start automatically Start python file on Background.

Comment: I Want To Do that in Python.Simple And Perfect,Easy To Use.

Comment: I can save starting time using: `import time` `time.ctime()`.But What About ShuttingDown.

Comment: If you want to do it in Python see https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/. I think what you need is in the `win32evtlog` module.

Comment: @BillBell Will you please give code of `win32evtlog` to use?

Comment: I can't because the code you need depends on two factors. You should go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/, click on the link 'Browse All Files' just under the 'Download' button, then the 'PyWin32' link on the page that appears, then 'Build 221 (as of today), and finally on the link that matches your requirement: Python version and Windows bandwidth.